# ArangoDB working together with letsenrcypt certificates

Tags: ssl, https, arangodb, lets-encrypt

Is there anyoune out there who got a running arangoDB database working with a letsencrypt certificate? I just can't find out to geht this running.

ArangoDB is running on a digitalOcean droplet and I could get it running togehter with a self-signed certificate following this [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40315135/arangod-conf-for-ssl). So arangoDB is sucessfully running on port: 8530

Now my approach was replacing the self-signed certificate with a letsencrypt cert.

So I added a subdomain in DigitalOcean to the droplet. e.g.: db.example.com an then generated the cert-files:

`sudo -H ./letsencrypt-auto certonly --standalone -d db.example.com`

You will end up with 4 files: `cert.pem` `chain.pem` `fullchain.pem` `privkey.pem`

As I understood, these files are:

```
Private Key --------> privkey.pem
Public Key ---------> cert.pem
Certificate Chain --> chain.pem
```

As described in the tutorial I mentioned, you nee the certificate and the key in one file. So i did

`cat chain.pem privkey.pem | sudo tee server.pem`

to have a file containing the certificate and the private key.

Then I modified the file `/etc/arangodb3/arangod.conf` to let arango know where the keyfile is and modified the ssl section:

```
[ssl]
keyfile = /etc/letsencrypt/live/db.example.com/server.pem
```

But after restarting arango, the server is not available. When trying to connect the browser to: `https://db.example.com:8530`. Firewall settings for the droplet should all be ok, because I could access this address with the self-signed cetificate before.

I then tried to modify the endpoint in `/etc/arangodb3/arangod.conf` from

```
endpoint = ssl://0.0.0.0:8530
```

to

```
endpoint = ssl://db.example.com:8530
```

and also

```
tcp://db.example.com:8530
```

None of it was working. Has somebody out there an idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Related feature request: [Split SSL Key File into Certificate and Private Key #2077](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/2077) (also see the referenced [ticket #2487](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/2487))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use the ip of the interface you want to use when specifying the endpoint e.g. `endpoint = ssl://42.23.13.37:8530` (`ip address` should list your interfaces along with addresses in use). Then it could help to use the fullchain.pem to create the server.prm (`cat fullchain.pem privkey.pem > server.pem`). Make sure the resulting `server.pem` is accessible and readable by the arangodb user. If the server is still not starting correctly please provide logs of the server. To access the logs use `systemctl -fu arangodb3.service` or follow the logs with `tail -f <logfile>` if you use some custom location for logging.

I have just tested a setup with letsencrypt certificates and it was working after ensuring all above points.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed instructions. Following these steps solved my problem. So at the end it was exactly the combination of the wrong IP settings and a none-accessible pem file.